# SMS Performance view dont showing the proper data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms, sendsmsactivity

I have a journey with different versions from which I send an SMS using the SMS activity. Checking the SMS Performance tab to see the tracking it seems there is some discrepancy between the count I have in the Journey and the one is displayed in SMS Analytics. I tried to change the dates but the number doesn't change.

Is there any other way to check the SMS tracking sent from a Journey?

[image]

Comment: Your SMS characters count makes it that SFMC counts it as two SMS instead of one. Journey Builder doesn't take this in consideration, that's why it shows the actual number of SMS's that were sent. 20 people entered your SMS activity, counted as 40 total sent by Journey Builder.

Comment: The number of characters in the SMS doesn't exceed the limit so there is only one message sent. On the other hand, the numbers doesn't change even if I put one year or one day in the date range.

Comment: That's strange. What is the number of characters in your SMS? Are you using any non-GSM characters? Doing so reduces the maximum characters count for 1 SMS to 70 characters.

Comment: I just checked it, there are more than 150 characters but the Concatenate Message option is enabled. There are no non-GSM characters.

Comment: Bear in mind that SFMC can split the SMS messages depending on the destination country. For example, if you are sending to Brazilian clients, the maximum character count is 160, but SFMC splits it when the SMS is longer than 140 characters. Check out this link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_character_counts.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am not sending emails to those countries, but in any case, it seems the 'issue' is related to that. How can I check then the tracking?

Comment: I'd check field SendSplitID from SMSMessageTracking to make sure the sms was split
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an out of the box solution to get SMS tracking of a specific journey. 
However, there are other ways to get what you want:

**Option 1:**

Query [SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) data view and tie the data back to your customers who received that specific SMS.

> This data view allows customers to view their send and receive
>   history. Information from this query relates to the owner of a private
>   short code or long code or a client using a shared short code to which
>   the subscriber has opted in.

**Option 2:**

Another way to go would be the **SMS Message Detail Report**.

> This report includes detailed tracking information about messages sent
>   from an account, including descriptive information about the message
>   and send status at an individual level.

These are the fields you'll get on your report's file. The only limitation is you can only create a Date based report and not Journey based.

-Date
-EID
-ClientID
-MessageName
-MessageType
-CampaignName
-MessageOrigin
-MessageText
-MobileNumber
-IsoCountryCode
-ShortCode
-Status
-MobileMessageTrackingID
-SubscriberKey

**Option 3:**

Or, you can check the SMS Analytics under Journey Analytics. It gives you a global preview about all your Journey's SMS performance (delivered, undelivered,..).

[image]